# After downloading VIM via Homebrew, how to add vimtex plug in?

Tags: vim, homebrew

I'm new to Vim and trying to configure my machine properly.  I'm unclear how to add the vimtex plug-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are many ways to manage plug-ins in Vim, my recommendation is for you to use [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as a plug-in manager. It's modern and efficient and still easy for beginners to use.

You can typically install it [with a single command](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/README.md#unix):

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Once you have it installed, just include the [plug-in configuration for vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/README.md#installation) in your vimrc file:

```
call plug#begin( ) 
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
call plug#end()
```

Then enter Vim and run this command to install the vimtex plugin:

```
:PlugInstall
```

That's all! vimtex should now be available. You can use `:PlugUpdate` to update vimtex (and any other plug-ins you manage with vim-plug) to its latest version.